# How to generate XSD file from a tree text in windows forms using C#

Tags: xml, winforms, xsd, treeview

I Have a requirement to generate XSD file from a tree view. Means, Tree node text should be the  elements of  XSD file. 
For example. Imagine i have the following tree.

Chapter

```
    Heading
       Section
           Paragraph
               Sentance
```

on a button click my out put should be

```
<xs:element name="Chapter" type="xs:string">
    <xs:element name="Heading" type="xs:string">
      <xs:element name="Session" type="xs:string">
        <xs:element name="Para" type="xs:string">         
        </xs:element>      
      </xs:element>    
    </xs:element>  
  </xs:element>
```

I have the following code but its returning only the first line. can anyone help ?

int i = 0;
        string XSD = string.Empty;

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       XSD=XSDString(XSD,tvMain.Nodes[0]);
       textBox1.Text = XSD.ToString(); 
    }

    private string XSDString(string XSD, TreeNode tnode)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < tnode.Nodes.Count; i++)
        {
            XSD = XSD + "<xs:element name=" + tnode.Nodes[i].Text + " "+ "type=" + "xs:string" + ">";
            XSDString(XSD, tnode.Nodes[i]);
            XSD = XSD + "</xs:element>";
        }
        return XSD;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer .. I just need XSD to hold on the value ..

XSD = XSDString(XSD, tnode.Nodes[i]);